# How to find all TODOs that are scheduled today or before today or TODOs that are not scheduled

Tags: org-mode

How to find all TODOs in org-mode that meet any of the following conditions:

- TODOs that are scheduled to be done today
- TODOs that are scheduled to be done before today
- TODOs that are not scheduled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Press `C-c a m` and enter the following search criteria:

```
SCHEDULED=""|SCHEDULED<"<tomorrow>"/TODO
```

For more information, you can visit [the official doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Matching-tags-and-properties.html), I also find [this tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html#todo-keyword-searches) extremely useful.